# Cricket spin bowler bouncer allowed or not?

Tags: rules, cricket

Is a spinner allowed to bowl a bouncer above the shoulder of the batsman?

Answer (score 4):

Bowling rules do not change by bowling type. So a bowler is allowed to bowl [two bouncers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouncer_%28cricket%29#ICC_Rules) in an over(in Test and ODI) and one in T20I in an over irrespective of bowling type. That means if a bowler bowls more than allowed bouncers in an over, it will be called a no ball.

Answer (score 4):

Yes Spinners can bowl bouncers and it has happened many times in the history of cricket.

Few are here:

[Afridi Bouncer to Lara](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXaGUpx5eAY)

[Shane Warne Bouncer to KP](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4j8G7DSyGfM)

Answer (score 0):

Spinner can also bowl any type of bowls which other bowlers bowls. There is no restriction. Spinners sometime bowl yorker or bouncer depending on the situation of the match. I remember many spinners using at least yorkers in matches.